# How to update session values from JSP in Struts 2

Tags: struts2, session-variables, textfield

I am using Struts 2.0. I have a Java Bean Person having fields perName, perAge, perMail & many more. I want to display a Map of Java Bean `{[1, person1], [2, person2])` on JSP and allow the user to update it from the same JSP using text fields. There are lot of variables in the bean and some of them are editable while some of them are not.

For example, perName is not editable while perAge is editable. I don't want to display non editable fields. If I use ediatable fileds only, after updating, I get non editable fields as null (perName is null after update). So I can't specify name attribute as it is changing at run time. So I am putting them in HTTP Session and displaying them. I am specifying name attribute of text field using `#session.person[iterator index].perAge`. Till this point everything works fine. But if I change the value in any text field & try to update, I get the old session attribute instead of changed one. I want the old session attribute with the new changed values and values of non editable fields should persist within user request. I don't want to use JavaScript. OGNL or expressions are most welcome.

```java
public class PersonDTO implements Serializable {
    private String perName;
    private int perAge;

    public String getPerName() {
        return perName;
    }

    public void setPerName(String perName) {
        this.perName = perName;
    }

    public int getPerAge() {
        return perAge;
    }

    public void setPerAge(int perAge) {
        this.perAge = perAge;
    }
}
```

```html
  <s:form action="updatePerson" id="updatePerson">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>AGE:<s:textfield name="#session.person.perAge" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><s:submit id="update" value="Update" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </s:form>
```

Comment: Put your code please what you had implemented so far?

Comment: public class PersonDTO implements Serializable {
 private String perName;
 private int perAge;
 
 public String getPerName() {
  return perName;
 }
 public void setPerName(String perName) {
  this.perName = perName;
 }
 public int getPerAge() {
  return perAge;
 }
 public void setPerAge(int perAge) {
  this.perAge = perAge;
 }
}
This is my Person bean.
I am displaying on JSP
<s:form action="updatePerson" id="updatePerson">
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td>AGE:<s:textfield name="#session.person.perAge" /></td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><s:submit id="update" value="Update" /></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</s:form>

Comment: In the action class, while putting class in session, 
 
HttpSession httpSes = req.getSession(true);
httpSes.setAttribute("person", perDTO);
 
 
While retrieving, 
HttpSession httpSes = req.getSession(true);
PersonDTO sesDTO = (PersonDTO) httpSes.getAttribute("person");

but I get age which is set while display & not the one edited in text field.

Thanks

Comment: Please make your question simple.

Comment: I am able to display age by using #session.person.perAge but if I change age on JSP, that age doesn't get set to session.

Comment: why dont you first get the edited value of textfields to your action then put that edited age to your session.

Comment: actually there will be many more variables just like Age. Also there might be some classes extending person & those classes may have their variables also. So it is not possible to create a variable in action class for each of them.

Comment: do not use session if it's not necessary, use status with iterator tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your support. After a day long GOOGLE, I found that it is not possible to update session directly using Struts tags. You can use session information for display and update session in scriplets but you can't update session directly. You may refer [Struts2 form to update object in Session map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719614/struts2-form-to-update-object-in-session-map) for more info. Once again thanks for help!!!